# Implementing iFog like app - Revealing inner UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiview, core-graphics

I'm trying to implement iFog like view, meaning a view when you can smear-like your finger on the screen and it will reveal what's beneath.

I have two problems with what I did so far:

1. When I first touch the screen, instead of revealing what's beneath in a circle, it shows the entire black rect. Next touches on screen work as expected.
2. When I scroll the mouse fast- not even that fast actually (still testing on simulator) - it doesn't seem to handle it well, as you can see by the gaps between the circles in the below picture.
   Maybe is has to do with improving the performance of what I did.

Picture attached to illustrate the black rect and the gaps.

[image]

My Code: (UIView Subclass)
Basically I'm showing the first image, and then revealing second image by traveling with my finger on screen.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    if (didStartTouching)
    {

        CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    

        CGContextAddArc(contextRef, rect.origin.x+CIRCLE_RADIUS, rect.origin.y+CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_RADIUS, 0, 360, 0);            

        CGContextClip(contextRef);

        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple"];

        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];    


    }
    else
    {
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_pic_1"];

        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];            
    }

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self revealImageInSet:touches];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self revealImageInSet:touches];    
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self revealImageInSet:touches];
}

-(void) revealImageInSet:(NSSet*)touches
{
    didStartTouching = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];     

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x-CIRCLE_RADIUS, point.y-CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_RADIUS*2, CIRCLE_RADIUS*2);

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of revealing the image only on the place where you got touches, you should reveal the image from your last touch point to your current touch point. Like making a line from the last touch to the current touch, then reveal whatever is behind that area. that would make it smoother.

Got no idea on the black rect on the first touch, sorry.

Comment: But if I'd reveal everything from last touch to current touch that would draw a line as you said, I don't want that. I want just the area where the user touches the screen at to be drawn. What did you mean by "behind this area" ? sample code would be awesome.

Comment: Your touch sequence is a continuous touch, right? A touch-and-drag gesture? I mean to say that you should reveal the lines between the points of each touch-and-drag gesture. So if the user does a downward drag, that entire area will be revealed in full, not in randomly spaced circles.

Comment: Basically, what I meant was you should track the "path" of the touches you are receiving, and reveal the image behind the path. Right now your code is just revealing the touch points. Join the touch points together to form your path. Of course, reset the path tracking when your touch-and-drag gesture ends.